# Can't Fetch API with Axios in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, fetch-api

I have done and tried the tutorial but the results are the same

when I want to retrieve an API with axios the results are just as illegible.

maybe this could be a repeated question but I was confused to finish it.

Please help

here's my code

```
constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            datas:[],
        }
    }
      componentDidMount() {
        axios
          .get('/jobs')
          .then(res => {
            const updatedData = res.datas.map(data => {
              return {
                  ...data
              };
            });
            this.setState({ datas: updatedData, err: null });
            // console.log(response)
          })
          .catch(err => {
            this.setState({ err: true });
          });
      }
```

and from render side

```
render(){
        let datas = <p style={{textAlign:'center'}}>Something went wrong!</p>

        if(!this.state.err){
           let datas = this.state.datas.map(data => {
                return <Card
                        key={data.id}
                        desription={data.desription}
                        company={data.company}
                        />
            })
        }
        return(
            <div>
                <section>
                    <Navigation/>
                </section>

                <section>
                    <SearchBox></SearchBox>
                </section>

                <section>
                    <Category></Category>
                </section>

                <main>
                    {datas}
                </main>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

from the console when I call it
[here's the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DLRG.png)

Card components image :
[from card components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6USO.png)

Comment: It appears to be a typo problem. Try `res.data` instead of `res.datas`.

Comment: still won't work sir..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what's the actual error? on the page.

and the `res.datas` should be `res.data` as the response does not have `datas`.

My account got blocked by some down votes questions, the funny thing is I have to re-edit them, even though I already have the accepted answer.I do not understand what's the point to do this.I am so frustrated by this stackoverflow system.

Now, I basically can do nothing but keep editing my questions, and they have all been answered. This is ridiculous !!!

Comment: there's no error but can't get the data from json.. i've tried console the 'datas' in part of render the value is [ ]

i dont know why? im new for reactjs

Comment: yes like I said there is no datas in the response, in ur pic it's called data, not datas

Comment: another thing is that datas is not a good name. try to change it if you can

Comment: I've changed the name to a 'job' and followed your way but the results remain the same

Comment: ok, the problem in ur code is this `const updatedData = res.datas.map(data => {` there is no datas in the response.u need to change it to data

Comment: so that line should be `const updatedData = res.data.map(data => {`

Comment: it's clearly shown on the pic u uploaded.

Comment: if there is still a problem, do u want to update ur latest code.?